# How to follow the activity of one specific file

Tags: bash, scripting

I have currently MAAS deployed on one of the servers. It all works (most of the time). Now I have added some lines in the WOL file for MAAS (/etc/maas/templates/power/ether_wake.template). I wanted to add some functionalities to the file.

I first made a bash script to know if everything worked as it should and after some bug fixes, it did. After that, I added it to the WOL file. From then on, it didn't worked anymore. Well, I am not new to bash script or anything, but I am not sure how to debug. When I look at the error logs, I can't see anything that is related to this file that gives me some kind of hint were it goes wrong. Therefore I am interested in knowing if there is some kind of CLI tool that can follow the output of that specific file over some period of time? Is this possible and in general am I tackling this problem in the right way?

Comment: Maybe the level of logging in not sufficient? Many software have a setting that lets you choose the quantity of messages that show up in the logs. Is there a "debug" settings for your WOL service?

Comment: Not that I know off. I have looked if I could set the verbose of the logging at a higher level, but I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: But for future use and other programs, wouldn't it be very useful to follow a specific file?

Comment: The problem is, you can only observe what the script shows you, hence the logging mechanism. Can you add commands in the file that would make it display some information at specific points?

Comment: If it's still a bash script being executed, just add `set -x` near the top, and bash will log everything for you. If it isn't still a bash script, please tell us _what it is_.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. What do you mean by “the output of that specific file”? Do you want to run a *command* periodically and watch for changes? Do you want to get an alert when a program writes to a file and know what program it is? Something else? What operating system is this happening on?

Answer (score 2):

A "CLI tool that can **follow the output of that specific file** over some period of time" would be `tail --follow=name --retry filename`. It will print lines of the file as they are added, and will read from the start of the file if it gets removed and re-created, but unfortunately it may miss lines if the file gets *truncated*. Test 1:

Terminal 1 (notice how it doesn't print `bar`):

```
$ tail --follow=name --retry test.log
tail: cannot open 'test.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: 'test.log' has appeared;  following new file
foo
tail: 'test.log' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
tail: 'test.log' has appeared;  following new file
baz
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ echo foo > test.log
$ echo bar > test.log
$ rm test.log
$ echo baz > test.log
```

Test 2, terminal 1:

```
$ rm test.log
$ tail --follow=name --retry test.log
tail: cannot open 'test.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: 'test.log' has appeared;  following new file
1
2
tail: test.log: file truncated
3
4
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ echo 1 > test.log
$ echo 2 >> test.log
$ echo 3 > test.log
$ echo 4 >> test.log
```

If you're trying to **follow the output of a *command*** you need to connect standard output (and possibly standard error) of that command to *something* - a terminal (simply run the command), a file (`command > my.log 2>&1`), or another command (`command 2>&1 | tail -f`).

Comment: Maybe, I was not clear enough, but following the error log is not that hard. It is more that one specific file (see first post) is used by MAAS at that specific moment that file is been read and executed the outcome of that file how can I follow that?

Comment: Then I still don't understand what you're trying to do. "The outcome of a file" doesn't make sense - do you mean the outcome of a *command?*

Comment: Ok, so I made the bash file first which worked. Then I added it to the MAAS file. It didn't do anything as expected. Now I suspect the file to fail somewhere. So I would like to see that when the that specific file is executed (with all the commands in it) to get some outcome compared to like running a bash script. For example when a bash script runs it says things like: "Failed to run command on line 6". I would like that kind of behaviour of the MAAS file, so I can see where it fails and how to debug.

Comment: Can you update the original question with what you are actually doing, what it does, and what you expect it to do? It really isn't clear.